# Google Scripts: Generating Email from Docs Loses Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to generate e-mails from a Google Doc. The idea is to keep a canned response in the Doc; as the Doc is updated, so is the canned response (as opposed to hard-coding it in the script). My company then uses the script to pull names from a Sheet and send them each an e-mail.

As of last week, however, formatting does not copy. For instance, if there is bold text in the Google Doc, the text is copied to the draft, but it is not bolded. As I am copying the HTML directly from the Doc to Gmail, the only thing I can think of is that Gmail doesn't respect css. Hyperlinks work, so I'm sure it respects html.

If the problem is that it doesn't respect css, what are my alternatives? Also, I am sure this worked last week as I have emails in my outbox I made with this script that contain bold text.

Sample Doc (*Tools > Script editor > Run* to put a draft of it in your Drafts folder. You must be logged in to Gmail and grant it permissions):

https://docs.google.com/document/d/15Y4lGHq-gsftz6JEzpvql57ZOBTe9CWgk0x29OW0onc/edit

Script code:

```
var docId="15Y4lGHq-gsftz6JEzpvql57ZOBTe9CWgk0x29OW0onc";

function makeNewEmail(){
  var subject="Test Email";
  var forDriveScope = DriveApp.getStorageUsed(); //needed to get Drive Scope requested
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+docId+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();

  GmailApp.createDraft(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), subject, "HTML is not enabled in your email client. Sad face!", {
    htmlBody: html,
  });  
}
```

Comment: The CSS in the email needs to be "inline"  You can't have a style tag, and then refer to the CSS with id's or class names.  But I have no idea why it was working, and now isn't.

Comment: So it should never have worked in the first place?

Comment: The documentation doesn't provide any detail about how the html should be structured.  So, I don't have an official answer about how the CSS should work.  Maybe someone else has a definitive answer.

Comment: But you think one solution could be using inline css?

Comment: I think that I'd try inline CSS to determine if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Per Sandy Good's suggestion, I was able to format the e-mail by having the script move the internal stylesheet to be inline.

Note it currently only handles .c tags (no h tags) and assumes head doesn't start with a .c tag.

```
var docId="1VnidBWgxxn1-287yo6Qf8CjKOlQhX-9qF1mIaWugTK4";
var classArray=[];

function makeNewEmail(){
  //get html from Doc
  var subject="Test Email";
  var forDriveScope = DriveApp.getStorageUsed(); //needed to get Drive Scope requested
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+docId+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();

  //docs uses css in the head, but gmail only takes it inline. need to move css inline.
  //DOES NOT HANDLE HEADER CLASSES (eg h1, h2).
  var headEnd = html.indexOf("</head>");
  //get everything between <head> and </head>, remove quotes
  var head = html.substring(html.indexOf("<head>")+6,headEnd).replace(/"/g,"");
  //split on .c# with any positive integer amount of #s
  var regex = /\.c\d{1,}/;
  var classes = head.split(regex);
  //get class info and put in an array index by class num. EG c4{size:small} will put "size:small" in classArray[4]
  var totalLength = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i < classes.length; i++){
    //assume the first string (classes[0]) isn't a class definition
    totalLength = totalLength + classes[i-1].length;
    var cNum = head.substring(totalLength+2,head.indexOf("{",totalLength)); //totallength+2 chops off .c, so get what's between .c and {
    totalLength = totalLength + 2 + cNum.length //add .c and the number of digits in the num
    classArray[cNum] = classes[i].substring(1,classes[i].indexOf("}")); //put what's between .c#{ and } in classArray[#]
  }

  //now we have the class definitions, let's put it in the html  
  html = html.substring(headEnd+7,html.indexOf("</html>")); //get everything between <html> and </html>
  var classMatch = /class=\"(c\d{1,} ){0,}(c\d{1,})\"/g
  //matches class="c# c#..." where c#[space] occurs any number of times, even zero times, and c#[no space] occurs after it, exactly once
  html = html.replace(classMatch,replacer); //replace class="c# c#..." with the definitions in classArray[#]

  //make the e-mail!
  GmailApp.createDraft(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), subject, "HTML is not enabled in your email client. Sad face!", {
    htmlBody: html,
  });
}

function replacer(match){
  var csOnly = match.substring(7,match.length-1); //class=" has 7 chars, remove the last "
  var cs = csOnly.split(" "); //get each c#
  var ret = "style=\""
  for(var cCount = 0; cCount < cs.length; cCount++){
    ret = ret + classArray[cs[cCount].substring(1)];
  }
  return ret+"\"";
}
```

This is obviously a little annoying (ideally, Gmail would either (1) allow internal stylesheets or (2) provide a function to import e-mails from Docs), but it works.