# HTML export from Google Doc not maintaining format when pasted into GMail

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

tl;dr - After exporting a Google Doc as an HTML file and pasting the HTML into a GMail draft it does not contain the formatting from the original Google Doc (other than hyperlinks).

Code snippet:

```
//copies the doc to HTML format
var htmlExport = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + docID + "&exportFormat=html";
var param = {
  method: "get",
  headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
};
var htmlExportText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(htmlExport,param).getContentText();

//the variables below (contactEmail & emailSubject) are both taken from a spreadsheet

//copies recent draft body to new email, then updates body of new email to include HTML export
var draftEmailBody = GmailApp.getMessageById(draftEmailID).getBody();
var draftToSend = GmailApp.createDraft(contactEmail,emailSubject,'',{htmlBody: htmlExportText + draftEmailBody}).getMessageId();
```

---

Long version:

I am building a mail merge that pulls contact info from a GSheet and uses GDoc as the template for the body. The GDoc has several bits of formatting in it (bold, italics, superscript) that, when exported as an HTML using the script above, appear in the GMail draft devoid of formatting (for some reason it leaves the hyperlinks). For some odd reason it even leaves the images from the doc!

The GMail draft pulled into the body (draftEmailBody) does, however, keep all it's formatting. I can only assume this means I'm doing something wrong by using getContentText but I don't know how else to go about it.

---

`(This is completely separate and I should probably just make another question for this, but I'm here so...)`

Separately, I wanted to have the script edit specific fields within the GDoc template, but I have run into 2 issues.

Problem 1 - I have found no way to replace specific text within a GMail draft.

Workaround 1 - I have the script edit the text in a GDoc instead, using repalceText. This, however, leads to:

Problem 2 - Using replaceText in a GDoc requires you to saveAndClose before the script can recognize the change. For some reason I can never get my script to open the GDoc again, despite including openByID in various places of the script!

Workaround 2 - I create a copy of the doc for each contact, replacing the text within that doc, then trash all of the copies on completion so there's no clutter. Quite clunky and slow but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the prettiest solution, I found something that helps:

[Google Scripts: Generating Email from Docs Loses Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930402/google-scripts-generating-email-from-docs-loses-formatting)

`(I may have messed this up as I had to remove parts of the code from my original that weren't part of this answer)`

---

```
var classArray=[];

function docToEmail() {
    //copies the doc to HTML format
    var htmlExport = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + docID + "&exportFormat=html";
    var param = {
      method: "get",
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    var htmlExportText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(htmlExport,param).getContentText();

    //the variables below (contactEmail & emailSubject) are both taken from a spreadsheet

    //copies recent draft body to new email, then updates body of new email to include HTML export
    var draftEmailBody = GmailApp.getMessageById(draftEmailID).getBody();
    var draftToSend = GmailApp.createDraft(contactEmail,emailSubject,'',{htmlBody: htmlExportText + draftEmailBody}).getMessageId();

    //grab CSS from doc
    //take everything between header
    var headEnd = htmlExportText.indexOf("</head>");
    var head = htmlExportText.substring(htmlExportText.indexOf("<head>")+6,headEnd).replace(/"/g,"");
    var regex = /\.c\d{1,}/;
    var classes = head.split(regex);
    var totalLength = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < classes.length; i++){
      totalLength = totalLength + classes[i-1].length;
      var cNum = head.substring(totalLength+2,head.indexOf("{",totalLength));
      totalLength = totalLength + 2 + cNum.length
      classArray[cNum] = classes[i].substring(1,classes[i].indexOf("}"));
    }

    //takes CSS and adds it to htmlbody
    urlBody = urlBody.substring(headEnd+7,urlBody.indexOf("</html>"));
    var classMatch = /class=\"(c\d{1,} ){0,}(c\d{1,})\"/g
    urlBody = urlBody.replace(classMatch,replacer);

    //copies draft body to new email, then updates body of new email
    var draftToSend = GmailApp.sendEmail(contactEmail,emailSubject,'',htmlBody: urlBody);
}

function replacer(match){
    var csOnly = match.substring(7,match.length-1); //class=" has 7 chars, remove the last "
    var cs = csOnly.split(" "); //get each c#
    var ret = "style=\""
    for(var cCount = 0; cCount < cs.length; cCount++){
      ret = ret + classArray[cs[cCount].substring(1)];
    }
    return ret+"\"";
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing your answer in a peer review. Just as a heads up, link-only answers are frowned upon on SO, I guess even if it is your own question. You should probably try to write out what you did to fix the issue.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I'll edit it to include the solution.